# Get Caret position with TestStack.White

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation, white-framework

I am using `White` to get a Microsoft Word Window and the Document as a TextBox like this:

```
Application a = Application.Attach(0x0000AC34);
Window w = a.GetWindow("Document1 - Word", InitializeOption.WithCache);
TextBox doc = w.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Document));
```

Is there a way to get the position of the caret? I am interested in both, the screen coordinates and the position within the text.

Ideally, I am looking for something in `White`.

If not, I know I can rely on `AutomationElement` and `TextPattern` ie.

```
TextPattern tp = doc.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;
TextPatternRange[] selectionRanges = tp.GetSelection();
// etc...
```

Is there any drawbacks in doing so? Are there better options I should consider?

Is there a way I can access the `IUIAutomationTextPattern2` interface?

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to do this in TestStack.White because TestStack.White only wraps the managed UIAv2 API. With [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI) you would be able to do this because they have a package for both UIAv2 and UIAv3. Here is the [wrapper](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.UIA3/Patterns/Text2Pattern.cs) they wrote around the UIAv3 COM dll.